# SQL Server DML TRIGGER

Tags: sql-server

I want try to monitor my SQL Server status, if any DML operation occurs, a trigger should record the log.

```
----create table-----
USE [master]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChangeLogin_Log]
(
    [ActionTime] [DATETIME] NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [Username] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL,
    [EventType] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL,
    [Data] [XML] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

----------------------TRIGGER ---------------------
CREATE TRIGGER [test] ON dbo.ChangeLogin_Log
FOR INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @data XML = eventdata();
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO ChangeLogin_Log(Username, EventType, Data)
    VALUES (CURRENT_USER,
            @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)'),
            @data)
END
GO
```

When I insert one record, the `ChangeLogin_Log` will not show the EventType, Data values - where is my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: Event data works for DDL triggers, not DML triggers. Are you seriously trying to store all the DML changes in a single table? That's basically reproducing the log functionality, which is a bad idea.

Comment: Your trigger will only fire when data is inserted into ChangeLogin_Log table, and it will only insert an additional row.